# Sum duplicate columns with pivot_wider()

Tags: r, shiny

I currently have a "long" dataframe that looks something like this:

```
# Phylum          Sample  Abundance
# Other           A1      17
# Other           A2      0
# Actinobacteria  A3      123
# Actinobacteria  B1      651
# Other           B2      22
# Actinobacteria  B3      844
# Firmicutes      A1      403
# Other           A2      42
# Firmicutes      A3      225
# Other           B1      16
# Other           B2      19
# Firmicutes      B3      556
```

and my goal is to make it look like this, where the data is pivoted to wide, but duplicate values are summed (such as Other/A2, and Other/B2):

```
# Phylum          A1    A2    A3    B1    B2    B3
# Actinobacteria  0     0     123   651   0     844
# Firmicutes      403   0     225   0     0     556
# Other           17    71    0     16    41    0
```

So far I've tried

```
newdata <- olddata %>% pivot_wider(names_from="Sample",values_from="Abundance",values_fill=0,values_fn=sum)
```

but this is giving the error `Error in values_fn[[value]] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable`. I've tried looking elsewhere on this site, but most people recommend making unique row names, which isn't an option in my case. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You have older version of `tidyr` I believe. Try to install the latest version and the error should be gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error couldn't be reproduced, but it may be better to place the `values_fill` and `values_fn` in a `list`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
olddata %>%        
    pivot_wider(names_from= Sample ,values_from= Abundance,
       values_fill=list(Abundance = 0),values_fn= list(Abundance = sum))
# A tibble: 3 x 7
#  Phylum            A1    A2    A3    B1    B2    B3
#  <chr>          <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 Other             17    42     0    16    41     0
#2 Actinobacteria     0     0   123   651     0   844
#3 Firmicutes       403     0   225     0     0   556
```

#### data

```
olddata <- structure(list(Phylum = c("Other", "Other", "Actinobacteria", 
"Actinobacteria", "Other", "Actinobacteria", "Firmicutes", "Other", 
"Firmicutes", "Other", "Other", "Firmicutes"), Sample = c("A1", 
"A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3", "A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3"
), Abundance = c(17L, 0L, 123L, 651L, 22L, 844L, 403L, 42L, 225L, 
16L, 19L, 556L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L
))
```